# Check if \w{1,4} also contains a dash with regex

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to match a string (test_one) with regex.
I'm splitting up these two in different groups:

```
\b(\w{1,4})_(\w*)
```

The first group can just be between 1 and 4 (alphabetic chars) in lenght and could contain a hyphen (not always), but \w only covers [a-zA-Z0-9_], so if I try this:

```
\b([a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,4})_(\w*)
```

And put a hyphen: "tes-t_one" it finds a match, but the full match is just: -t_one.

How can I get match on whole first group when a hyphen is in the string?

The expected output is it should match for example test_one or tes-t_one. Not -test_one or test-_one

Comment: There are 5 chars now, right? `\b([\w-]{1,5})_(\w*)`. BTW, `\w` matches `_`, maybe you want `\b([-\w-[_]]{1,5})_(\w*)`? Or do you mean you want to match 4 *word* / *alphanum* chars after the word boundary, and there can be a single (or more?) `-`s anywhere inside the part between a word boundary and `_`?

Comment: Please provide exact *real* requirements for the new pattern. Maybe you need `\b((?:-?[^\W_]){1,4})_(\w*)`?

Comment: For questions on this topic, it helps to provide an input and the desired output

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Yes I want to match 4 a-zA-Z0-9 and there could be a single - inside (not before or after).

Comment: @Kilazur: The input is there? test_one/tes-t_one. I've added the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a [**conditional construct**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/alternation-constructs-in-regular-expressions#conditional-matching-with-an-expression) will help you: if there is a single hyphen in between alphanumeric symbols after a word boundary and before  a `_`, then match `{1,5}` chars, else match `{1,4}` alphanumeric or `-` chars in the first group.

```
\b((?([^\W_]+-[^\W_]+_)[-\w-[_]]{1,5}|[^\W_]{1,4}))_([^\W_]*)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cb%28%28%3F%28%5B%5E%5CW_%5D%2B-%5B%5E%5CW_%5D%2B_%29%5B-%5Cw-%5B_%5D%5D%7B1%2C5%7D%7C%5B%5E%5CW_%5D%7B1%2C4%7D%29%29_%28%5B%5E%5CW_%5D*%29&i=test_one%20tes-t_one%20testt_o&r=___&o=m).

**Details**:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `((?([^\W_]+-[^\W_]+_)[-\w-[_]]{1,5}|[^\W_]{1,4}))`  - Group 1:

  - `(?` - if...
  - `([^\W_]+-[^\W_]+_)`  - there is a sequence of:

    - `[^\W_]+` - 1 or more alphanumerics
    - `-` -  a hyphen
    - `[^\W_]+` - 1 or more alphanumerics
    - `_`  - an underscore
  - `[-\w-[_]]{1,5}` - 1 to 5 alphanumerics or `-` symbols
  - `|` -  else
  - `[^\W_]{1,4})` - match 1 to 4 alphanumerics
- `_` - an underscore
- `([^\W_]*)` - 0+ alphanumerics (letters or digits).

To make the pattern match ASCII only, pass the `RegexOptions.ECMAScript` option to the regex constructor.

Note that `[^\W_]` is equal to `[\w-[_]]` matching any letters or digits (the `_` is subtracted from the `\w` pattern).

Comment: Thanks. Haven't had the time to try it it, will try it and get back to you :)